# FastCGI Configuration errors - upload and image processing fail

Tags: php, wordpress, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

My wordpress is behaving strangely, after I changed the php handler to fcgi

```
[Sat Dec 03 02:13:06 2011] [warn] [client 66.249.72.226] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Sat Dec 03 02:13:06 2011] [error] [client 66.249.72.226] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Sat Dec 03 02:18:11 2011] [warn] [client 94.139.59.97] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds, referer: http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/upload.php
[Sat Dec 03 02:18:11 2011] [error] [client 94.139.59.97] Premature end of script headers: admin.php, referer: http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/upload.php
[Sat Dec 03 02:18:18 2011] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 24965 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

How can i Fix this? I made the php-handler change via cPanel, along with a  php upgrade to 5.3.8.

Comment: I'm having the same errors, did you find a way to fix that ?

Comment: I reinstalled apache with php compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with your FCGI settings in order to fix this. This usually speaks of the fcgi scripts dying too fast. 
Check out http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html for more information. For a start you could use:

```
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 8
FcgidMaxProcesses 150
FcgidIdleTimeout 60
FcgidProcessLifeTime 120
FcgidIdleScanInterval 30
```